# Missing "start a bounty" link on stackoverflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, bounties

I don't have a `start a bounty` link on stackoverflow. On both meta and superuser the link exists but not on SO (where I have enough reputation).

My user id is 3848.

This issue reproduces on multiple machines and in three different browsers (so it's probably not a client side issue).

Comment: Do you already have a bounty started on a different question?

Comment: Nope, I had a bounty more than half a year ago but not since.

Comment: Is the question not old enough?

Comment: I went to question #178634 which was asked on October 2008 and no link there either (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178634)

Comment: That's funny, I see a bounty link on that question.

Comment: I see the link, too. (But I haven't started a bounty on SO before)

Comment: @mmyers and @Tobias, I don't think this bug applies to all users that's why I specified my UID.

Comment: It's not a problem of reputation too, as Motti has more reputation than I do on Stack Overflow, but I am able to see the link.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Things that would prevent bounty link from showing:

- you already have an active bounty on any question (only one is allowed)
- you lack sufficient rep to start a bounty (100 is the minimum)
- the question is not yet *2* days old (the minimum age)

When I log in as my test account with 178 rep -- our old pal Eggs McLaren -- I do see the 'start a bounty' link [on that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178634), so I can't reproduce this.

I suspect you already have an active bounty in the system on someone else's questions?

edit: I see -- **you started a bounty, then deleted the question you had the bounty on while the bounty was still active.** It was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480193). I cleared the bounty which deletes the bounty vote.

Comment: Huh, so now bounties no longer block a question from being deleted or closed? That's interesting.

Comment: @grace, I think you could delete them as long as it was your question

Comment: Either block the deletion, or auto-clear the bounty...?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, that solved things. Are you going to add a general solution to prevent this from happening again (as per @Jon's suggestions)

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem was "the question is not yet 2 days old (the minimum age)" :)

Comment: @Jeff, I think, now the sufficient reputation required is [75](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).

Comment: Something else I ran into ... a single user can only have three outstanding bounties at a given time. You have to award one of the bounties to offer another one.

Comment: My problem is "the question is not yet 2 days old (the minimum age)". I thought that I can only start a bounty on the first 2 day