# What would prevent me from adding a bounty to a question?

Tags: support, bounties, old-questions

I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591841/distribution-of-items-from-x-sets-of-plants-in-y-baskets-equally) from April, with 0 answers.  I would really like to see the solution of it.  I've starred it and upvoted it, and even left a comment, but I don't think it's being bumped.

I want to offer a bounty, but for some reason there is no link at the bottom of the post on my screen that allows me to do so.  What is going on here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing "start a bounty" link on stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54726/missing-start-a-bounty-link-on-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To offer a bounty:

- You must have at least 100 reputation
- The question must be at least 2 days old
- You have no other bounties active

If you pass all those critera, there is a [bug related to bounty offering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54726/missing-start-a-bounty-link-on-stackoverflow).

If you add a bounty on a question which gets deleted before the bounty expires, then the bounty is still "active". This needs to be fixed by a moderator or super-admin.