# Can't start bounty on question after two days, did I not consider anything?

Tags: support, status-completed, bounties, usability

I want to start a bounty on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995924/tfs-merge-chooses-wrong-base-revision-for-3-way-merge) question. It was asked more than two days ago, but I can't see the start bounty link.

Now, I'm at SO for quite a while and have sucesfully used the bounty system in the past, did anything relevant change about the process? Maybe I'm just being stupid and can't find the link but I used `Ctrl+F bounty`...

Comment: Odd. I see "start a bounty," plain as day. Did you do a hard refresh?

Comment: Do you currently have a bounty on another question? [If so, you cannot post a bounty on this one until the other one finishes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71969/why-cant-i-offer-a-bounty-on-a-question). Note that if you can't visibly find one, if you ever had (under very rare circumstances) a live bounty deleted, then you'd be pretty much bounty-blocked until that zombie bounty is taken care of.

Comment: @Grace: No, no other bounty.

Comment: @Popular: Tried Internet Explorer (my default is chrome), and still no bounty link.

Comment: [The answer to this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54994/what-would-prevent-me-from-adding-a-bounty-to-a-question) details every scenario in which you would not have access to a bounty (though it is old, as the bounty rep requirement is now only 75). So I'm inclined to believe you have an active, but deleted, bounty somewhere. There's not much other explanation to be found.

Comment: @Johannes Do you see the link on other questions?

Comment: @Pollyanna: Tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979023/why-are-there-java-singleton-classes-when-would-you-need-to-use-one, no bounty.

Comment: The deleted bounty trick happened to me awhile ago.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75866/cant-place-a-bounty-on-meta-questions Flag the question for moderator attention and they'll fix it for you.

Comment: @Pollyanna As it were, your incident actually refreshed my memory of that scenario, so I had the link ready for this one. ♪

Comment: Can also happen when a question is migrated if you have an active bounty on it.

Comment: Seems the Bounty system is a bit fragile... Anyway, have flagged my question for Moderator Attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was somehow a bounty on a deleted post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059109/internships-for-pre-freshman - fixed.

Comment: That was almost over a year ago... :-) A lot has changed since then... Thank you very much for fixing the bounty! In the future, could we make the bounty system more robust with regards to deleted questions?