# Cannot add bounty to my own question (after more than two days)

Tags: support, bounties, specific-question

This is my question: [What is the best tool for documenting/generate reference for a RESTful/HTTP RPC API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6254171/751151)

I am unable to offer a bounty on this question, despite the question having been asked several days ago. I did edit the question (before the first two days had passed).

Is this the same issue that was responsible for [Can't start bounty on question after two days, did I not consider anything?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79723/163318)

Comment: I see a link for Start a Bounty. Have you tried flagging the post for attention?

Comment: Looks like you have a bounty on a deleted question

Comment: Interesting. I cannot see the link. I have flagged the question too, didn't think to do that before asking this question.

Comment: Users may now have up to three simultaneous bounties active, so this situation will never happen again. (A similar problem could occur with trying to start a fourth simultaneous bounty, of course.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an open bounty on

[What's the best tool to manage documentation for Restful API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436506/whats-the-best-tool-to-manage-documentation-for-restful-api)

For the next 8 hours

Comment: Is there an easy way to see the open bounties you have?

Comment: From FAQ - There can only be 1 active bounty per question **and** per user at any given time. Missed this on the FAQ. Makes sense!